# Are the Different Characters Unique from a Gameplay Perspective?

Tags: rayman-origins

Every so often as I collect more and more *Electoons*, I get a notification that I've unlocked a new character at the *Snoring Tree*.  Once I visited there, I found that there are in fact, a variety of characters to choose from, including Rayman, Globox, and some Teensies.  It looks like I can also unlock many more based on the number of empty floating bubbles.

Are the different characters simply re-skins of one another?  Do any of them have unique qualities that might affect the gameplay?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are minor differences - like some characters can't be stacked, some of the teensy wizards have slightly different magic attacks, and the princess can grab ledges instead of falling, but I can't find confirmation anywhere, I'll have to look into it further...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't find anything from the other characters. I think they only are re-skins. Sadly, they don't have any unique qualities that difference one versus an other other then the appearance.

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I can't imagine the hitboxes of the teensies could be the same size as the hitboxes of Rayman and Globox.

Comment: @GnomeSlice After playing a bit with all the different characters, I'm inclined to believe they're right. The hitboxes do appear to be the same from what I can tell and are most obvious on the swimming and floating levels. Globox, the big one, can get away with touching things slightly while the smaller ones can't. All have the same move types as well even though animations are different.

Answer (score 0):

Well raymans punch seems to be the biggest, and Globox is extremely useful for stacking players, as he's the tallest.

Comment: Is your answer based on assumptions or facts? Can you link to a reference?